# Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with false

Tags: node.js, sass, archlinux, gulp-sass, node-sass

Getting this error on Arch Linux with node-sass. I'm using it with [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass).

```
Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with false
```

Versions

```
$ gulp -v
[19:43:15] CLI version 3.9.1
[19:43:15] Local version 3.9.1

$ npm -v
3.9.0
```

Node

```
$ node -v
v6.2.0
```

Even using this command `npm rebuild node-sass` is not changing anything.

Comment: I have the same issue. What node version are you using btw?

Comment: @antjanus Updated to the question.

Comment: Should work after `gulp-sass` updates the dependency to `node-sass` https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1484

Comment: @PeteTNT What could be the solution till then?

Comment: @JitendraVyas you could try updating your `node-sass` manually with `npm install node-sass` (or by forking the `gulp-sass` and bumping up the version  in the package.json)

Comment: @PeteTNT I have already tried this `npm rebuild node-sass`

Comment: @JitendraVyas Rebuild node-sass doesn't update the version, just rebuilds the binaries and such from the existing versions. Run `npm install node-sass` first.

Comment: @Pete TNT - Even that didn't work

Comment: npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.1

Comment: `node-sass` is deprecated use `sass`.

Answer (score 333):

run `npm rebuild node-sass`

or

run `sudo npm rebuild node-sass`

Comment: This worked very well for the similar error in my Mac OSX environment!

Comment: Btw. It could happened, when you updated your NodeJS and node-sass was compiled with previous NodeJS version.

Comment: can anyone explain why this works? will this need to be done every time I clear out my node_modules folder? or is sass installed as some kind of global 'service'

Comment: also I'm very confused how a clean install in June 2017 (on Windows) leads to this error when Node 6 came out over a year ago? why wasn't this just a temporary error at the time. this solution did work for me - but I really would like to understand why!

Comment: Documentation for npm rebuild says "This command runs the npm build command on the matched folders. This is useful when you install a new version of node, and must recompile all your C++ addons with the new binary.". I know I started hitting this after upgrading node, so maybe that's the same for everyone else here?

Comment: Worked for me too… But presumably this is a bug in the build system?

Comment: Nah, it just happens when NodeJS is upgraded to to C++ addons.

Comment: yea it's working for me.. i think because node-saas need syncronize with latest of new parts from latest version of node.js..

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to help this very similar error: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1898

Comment: `npm rebuild node-sass` worked great for me in Kubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 139):

in some cases you need to uninstall and install node-sass library. Try:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev node-sass
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

Comment: Not working for me

Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 4.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

Comment: This worked on Mojave. No need to run `npm rebuild node-sass`

Comment: I do not know, how it works.
But it worked for me like a charm.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 54):

I managed to solve this issue using the command below.

npm audit fix - **Worked for me**

```
npm audit fix
```

I tried - **Didn't work for me**

```
sudo npm rebuild node-sass
```

Then I tried - **Didn't work for me**

```
npm uninstall --save-dev node-sass
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

Answer (score 44):

**As of July 2019 with Node v12** -

node-sass v4.11.0 doesn't work with Node 12.

I faced this problem when I upgraded node to v12.

Rebuilding node-sass as suggested by the other answers didn't work as well.

Upgrading node-sass to v4.12.0 fixed it for me.

`npm install node-sass@4.12.0`

Comment: Better to use `npm install node-sass@latest`

Comment: working perfectly in the way suggested with node@12

Comment: This is how my issue also got solved! Thank you @Sashi for sharing!

Answer (score 30):

Uninstall and reinstall `node-sass` and it will find missing binary for itself.

```
npm uninstall --save-dev node-sass
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

If issue is not resolved using above commands, there may be problem with your node version. Check that your node version supports node-sass version. Chose a stable node version and repeat above commands to fix this issue.

Below is the compatibility table of the node with node-sass:-

```
NodeJS | Supported node-sass version | Node Module
Node 19     8.0+                        111
Node 18     8.0+                        108
Node 17     7.0+                        102
Node 16     6.0+                        93
Node 15     5.0+                        88
Node 14     4.14+                       83
Node 13     4.13+, <5.0                 79
Node 12     4.12+                       72
Node 11     4.10+, <5.0                 67
Node 10     4.9+, <6.0                  64
Node 8      4.5.3+, <5.0                57
Node <8     <5.0                        <57
```

If issue is still not fixed, check node-sass supported environment's list:-
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/

Comment: This did it for me! Don't know why if you don't specify the version it will install the latest one but not the one that better suits your environment, is that the normal approach for npm?

Comment: The magic combo for me was going back to node @ 12.22.8.  This allowed node-sass to install fine.

Answer (score 11):

Kindly change your node version and use a stable version of node. This happened with me when I was trying with node version 15+ and npm version 7+. I changed my node version to 14.0.0 simply using nvm.

try:

```
nvm use 14.0.0
```

then:

```
npm run start or node-sass
```

Comment: `nvm install 12.18.2` -- this work for me.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using arch-linux environment, You can uninstall node-sass using the command below:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev node-sass
```

then install sass using the commands below:

```
npm add -D sass
```

if you are using yarn package enter the commands below

```
yarn add -D sass
```

or

```
yarn add _D sass
```

** Great it works like a charm for me **

Answer (score 8):

You should also check your version of nodejs. I was on a version 9 of node js which isn't officially supported **at this time of writing**. Reverting back to version 6.11.4 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Node 8 also will work. You can get node 8 from https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node/v8.12.0/
node-v8.12.0-x64.msi

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this applies here, but for me, I just removed node_modules and reinstalled (npm install). Issue was fixed.

Answer (score 5):

**npm install** 
or
**npm rebuild node-sass**

fixes the problems

please refer: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1764

Answer (score 4):

Go the path where node-sass is present and run this command

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

This solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

That worked for me:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 6.0.0
```

Comment: For anyone wondering what `n` is, [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n). Quote: _Node.js version management: no subshells, no profile setup, no convoluted API, just **simple**. (Unfortunately `n` is not supported on Windows yet.)_

Answer (score 3):

Error I was getting, Module "build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (72)".

First, tried:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

nothing helpful, then tried

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g node-sass
```

Worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

We had this problem on several OS. Considering node-sass is deprecated, we simply migrated to Dart Sass based on this [how to migrate from node-sass to dart sass](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated#:%7E:text=If%20you%27re%20a%20user,switch%20to%20Dart%20Sass%27s%20CLI.) and this [In Vue CLI how do I use sass instead of node-sass (default for sass-loader)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61198331/in-vue-cli-how-do-i-use-sass-instead-of-node-sass-default-for-sass-loader) (we have a vueJS project) and it works. We did:

```
npm install -D sass-loader sass
```

delete `node-sass` in package.json

```
npm prune
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using wsl 2 with `Ubuntu-20.04` and was facing this problem. You have to downgrade your node version as `node-sass` (at this moment) doesn't work with `version 17 (latest)` and even `version 16 (stable)`. However, switching to `version 14` helped me.

Run these commands

`sudo npm install -g n`

`sudo n 14.17.5`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for windows x64 Platform.

Just updated the package.json with newer version of node-saas instead rebuild because in order to rebuild you need visual studio build environment which is suck to install for a dependency :)…

go with latest node-saas you should be fine:

```
"node-sass": "^4.11.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a node version issue.

Check your node version with

```
node -v
```

you can install node version manager to make life easier. See

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script

```
Install:
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash

Usage: 
nvm install <version>       Download and install a <version> 
nvm use <version>           Modify PATH to use <version> nvm ls        
List versions (installed versions are blue)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Only solution Work  For macOs and Window**

```
npm uninstall --save-dev node-sass
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

Answer (score 1):

**Node-sass incompatibility with the node version** was the issue in my case. I had node-sass v4.13.1 with node version 14+ running in my machine. On seeing the [release tag](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.13.1), I found that node version 14+ was not supported. So using the nvm I downgraded my node to 13+ and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to bump down to node 12 from node 16

Answer (score 1):

had to downgrage nodejs according to supported version table https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your shell has npm loaded.

I didn't find this answer here.
I kept hitting this intermittently until I realized, my shell doesn't auto-load nvm - and so, when I ran build I'd hit this.

HTHs someone.

Answer (score 0):

Remove node_modules/node-sass folder & run
npm install (this may take some time based on the dependencies)
then run
npm run build

This should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall node-sass

npm i node-sass@4.7.2

https://dev.to/letsbsocial1/node-sass-and-node-910-4ol

Answer (score 0):

Remove node modules: **$rm-rf node_modules**

Re install node modules: **$npm install**

Answer (score 0):

If uninstall & install `node-sass` did not work try to **remove** `node_modules` folder and `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

`npm i @ionic/app-scripts` Was the only thing that had any impact for me.

Answer (score 0):

npm audit fix
works for me like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Its just a version issue Install node version 10 it will work fine

```
npm install node@10
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.none of the solutions worked.So I tried my usual response of restarting my mac which I do quite rarely and the issue got resolved.
When you dont shutdown or restart your Mac for a long time,such random issues occur.

Answer (score 0):

Install dart-sass

npm install node-sass@npm:sass

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sass/node-sass

I check the version table in the repo and modify the node-sass version in the dependencies in the package.json file according to the node version.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "4.14.0",
  }
```

[a quick guide for minimum and maximum supported versions of node-sass:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpJTQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

In case of **Node v16.19.0** and **Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS** I've updated sass-loader to "^13.2.0" version.

```
"sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

`yarn upgrade` helped me.

After this in my react app I started to get another error "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined" - then:
`yarn add react-scripts@latest` helped me finally to run this FE app (scripts were updated from 3.0.1 ver to 5.0.1)