# Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime

Tags: html, node.js, npm, sass, gulp

I have some problems with using nodejs. I always used nodejs to use gulp and sass for my projects with HTML. 
Never had problems with it until the following error: ***Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (57).***
I already have npm globally installed with: npm -g install gulp. Then I could always type in ***gulp*** and then my HTML page worked, but now I get the above error.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Hopefully I use stackoverflow well, it's my first question, so apologize if I do it wrong.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415134/error-node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-windows-64-bit-w)

Comment: See workaround mentioned on ["Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (108)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979606/node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-windows-64-bit-with-un/75234435#75234435)

Answer (score 4):

Run this command to solve this issue.

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

if this didnt work then use below :

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

Comment: This command didn't work for me but the same command with --force worked like a charm!

Comment: `npm rebuild node-sass --force` Terminal: "I sure hope you know what you are doing.". Me: ...

Answer (score 2):

I guess your node version might be above node js 9

Answer (score 2):

The link from the stack trace below helped me in resolving this issue.

```
Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.2
```

This link(`https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.2`) clearly shows node versions which are supported.

```
    OS      Architecture    Node
    Windows x86 & x64       0.10, 0.12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    ...     ...             ...
```

I was using `node 10.15.3` which is clearly not supported. So,downgraded the node version to `8.11.1`, executed `npm install` again. Got the following message.

```
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64)

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
```

As suggested, ran `npm rebuild node-sass --force`. And the issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Having python 2.7.* in path instead of 3.* and then reinstalling node-sass `npm uninstall node-sass && npm install node-sass` worked for me as is mentioned in other [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48933672/2331858).

So checking your `python --version` could be something to start with.