# Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit laravel

Tags: npm, node-sass

**my config**

linux ubuntu **16.04 64bits**
node -v **v6.10.3**
npm -v **5.5.1**

npm ls node-sass 
/home/myname/Code/myproject
└─┬ laravel-elixir@6.0.0-16
----└─┬ gulp-sass@2.3.2
--------└── node-sass@3.13.1

***the error ---------------------------***

Starting 'sass'...
[14:53:46] 'sass' errored after 91 ms
[14:53:46] Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (57)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.13.1
    at module.exports (/home/myname/Code/myproject/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
    at Object. (/home/myname/Code/myproject/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

ps: **I do (npm rebuild node-sass) and the same problem**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

possibly duplicate of [node-sass environment error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324519/node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-linux-64-bit-with-false).

The fix for me was following. 
There are 2 things to manage.

1. If you want to keep the node-sass version as specified in package.json then you will have to play with node and npm version. for me i had to keep specified version let say 3.10.1 so i used node 6.12.3 and npm v3.10.10 and then go to root folder of project and do `npm install`.

   2. If you are using proper version of node and npm then remove `node_modules` and again do `npm install`. this might work 
      or one more thing you can do is `npm uninstall --save node-sass` and then
      again do `npm install --save node-sass`

Comment: Good call m8. Cheers!

Comment: @Sankalp. Good find. I wish I would have read that ticket before I deleted my node_modules directory and rebuilt it.