# Fresh Laravel Homestead 8.0.1: npm run dev fails to compile and npm ci fails to install. Something with cross-env?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, homestead

I recently upgraded my Homestead from 6.3 to fresh Laravel Homestead 8.1.

I `ssh`'ed into the VM as usual to compile assets in my Laravel project via `npm run dev` and it started failing.

I was getting issue that Node Sass does not yet support your current environment ([similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324519/node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-linux-64-bit-with-false)) but running:

`sudo npm rebuild node-sass` and `npm uninstall --save node-sass` and `npm install --save node-sass` didn't help.

When I completely remove `node_modules` via `rm -rf node_modules` or do `npm ci` it install stuff and fails at the end with:

[image]

No idea how to fix this. My node and npm versions are below:

`node -v` gives `v12.7.0`

`npm -v` gives `6.10.2`

`package.json` is:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
    "tdd": "npm run test -- --watch --notify"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.0.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.2.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "babel-jest": "^22.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jest": "^22.1.4",
    "jest-vue-preprocessor": "^1.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "pace": "github:HubSpot/pace#v1.0.2",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.4",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.0.7",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/tests/Javascript/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^vue$": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-vue-preprocessor"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.8.0",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-scroller": "^2.0.0",
    "debounce": "^1.2.0",
    "jquery-datatables-checkboxes": "^1.2.11",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1"
  }
}
```

Can somebody give me any hint? I'm happy to provide additional output from any logs if needed. I'm blocked by this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full reset did the job:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

then

`npm run dev`

[image]

I committed new `package-lock.json` into the repository. Can somebody at least explain what was the culprit?