# How to quickly reflect a change in a component's browser worked?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, visual-studio-code, vuejs2

While working on a vue project, in the console I have executed: npm run watch, so when saving a small or big change in a component or some part of the vue project, I go to the console and I must give enter to start the compilation . Thus:

[image]

and I must give time until it ends

[image]

Then I must go to my browser tab where I show the project and I must refresh the entire page to see the change.

This process sometimes takes time. I ask if there is a faster way to work, that is, I make a change, I save in visual code and without refreshing the browser, can I see the change? Maybe it's some npm or visual studio code plugin

Thank you very much for the time.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:  OP is using Laravel Homestead.  Was not mentioned at first, question tag changed now.

---

This sounds like an old version of Vue CLI, so it may be time to update if possible.  Either way, try:

```
npm run serve
```

OR

```
npm run dev
```

The standard Vue CLI dev command now is `npm run serve`.  If these fail (unlikely), check your `package.json` and see what `scripts` are available

```
"scripts": {
   "serve": "[]",
   "dev": "[]"
}
```

Each one of these `scripts` is an item you can `npm run`.  Check the [Vue CLI script docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve) for more.

Comment: When I do npm run dev, it basically starts loading everything, but when it reaches 100%, it just ends the process in the cmd and when I run npm run serve it shows npm ERR! missing script: serve.

Comment: scripts in package.json: `"scripts": { "dev": "npm run development", "development":"cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",`

Comment: `"watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js", "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll","hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js","prod": "npm run production","production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js" }`

Comment: Are you using Laravel?

Comment: Yes it is. I find myself running Laravel Homestead and to compile the vue part, the components I already use the CMD and I run npm run watch.

Comment: Hmm.  You can see in `scripts` that `npm run dev` is the correct way.  The only difference between `npm run dev` and `npm run watch` is the `--watch` and `--watch-poll` flags.  This may be a problem with your Laravel or Node installation or version.

Comment: You could try `npm run hot`

Comment: `npm run hot ` show this "No parser and no filepath given, using 'babel' the parser now but this will throw an error in the future. Please specify a parser or a filepath so one can be inferred.'"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304281/fresh-laravel-homestead-8-0-1-npm-run-dev-fails-to-compile-and-npm-ci-fails-to