# Node Sass Error due to Unsupported Environment OS X 64-bit with unsupported runtime

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, node-sass

Unable to build webpack production due to Node Sass Module build failed.

Below is Node Sass Error

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think this is causing your error? What is the error message you are receiving? Where are these files being used? Please create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out. I have included additional screenshots of the error.

Comment: No problem.  A quick Google shows that this is as the error states, probably an issue with the Node Sass library.  I can't see why the posted devDependencies would have any effect on loading CSS files.  Have you tried [this link](https://medium.com/@proustibat/how-to-fix-error-node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-os-x-64-bit-with-c1b3298e4af0)?

Comment: I see, i will edit the post. I tried npm rebuild node-sass, unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Ah, wish I could be more help, I've never used that particular library, but the dependencies you've listed shouldn't affect building/loading CSS files at all.  Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324519/node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-linux-64-bit-with-false) will be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to able to fix the Node Sass module build error by uninstalling and reinstalling node sass using the command below.

```js
npm uninstall --save-dev node-sass

npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

Comment: What it worked for me is delete node_modules directory and execute `npm install`, and then execute the command above from Kevin Lee.

Answer (score 0):

Please downgrade your node version , I have used 12.18.1 and my error was gone